# How can I generate Javadoc comments in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, javadoc

Is there a way to generate Javadoc comments in Eclipse? If so, what is it?

Comment: I tried the alternate answer(2 years ago) and didn't like it, so consider it a dup or not.

Comment: Duplicate or not, this is the top result when googling "eclipse generate javadoc"

Answer (score 367, accepted):

For me the `/**<NEWLINE>` or <kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>J</kbd> (or <kbd>⌘</kbd>-<kbd>⌥</kbd>-<kbd>J</kbd> on a Mac) approach works best.

I dislike seeing Javadoc comments in source code that have been auto-generated and have not been updated with real content.  As far as I am concerned, such javadocs are nothing more than a waste of screen space.

IMO, it is much much better to generate the Javadoc comment skeletons one by one as you are about to fill in the details.

Comment: To save space, fold it!

Comment: @Pascal - I'd prefer to delete it/them, or not generate it/them in the first place.  IMO, generated javadoc comments add zero value ... unless you count a bogus boost to the comment-to-code ratio as "value".

Comment: important note: If using shift-alt-j, don't forget to place the cursor first in the method you want to document otherwise your comment will be added at the top of the file for the class.

Answer (score 87):

`Shift-Alt-J` is a useful keyboard shortcut in Eclipse for creating Javadoc comment templates.

Invoking the shortcut on a class, method or field declaration will create a Javadoc template:

```
public int doAction(int i) {
    return i;
}
```

Pressing `Shift-Alt-J` on the method declaration gives:

```
/**
 * @param i
 * @return
 */
public int doAction(int i) {
    return i;
}
```

Comment: On a Mac, it's `⌘-alt-J`

Comment: You just made my life SOOOOO much better!  I'll thank you every time I use shift-alt-J -- and every time I look brilliant when I show it to coworkers!

Answer (score 40):

[JAutoDoc](http://jautodoc.sourceforge.net/):

> an [Eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/) Plugin for automatically adding Javadoc and file headers to your source code. It optionally generates initial comments from element name by using [Velocity](http://velocity.apache.org/) [templates](http://jautodoc.sourceforge.net/templates.html) for Javadoc and file headers...

Comment: better than the built in alt-shift-j

Comment: And shortcut is `Ctrl` + `Alt` + `J`

Answer (score 27):

You mean menu Project -> Generate Javadoc   ?

Comment: That menu item isn't in any of the perspectives I use.

Comment: It's on my Eclipse, and the only extra things I've installed are Google Web Toolkit and FindBugs.  (This is Ganymede, not Europa.  Maybe you need to upgrade?)

Comment: I only have the gwt perspective, eclipse v 3.5.1

Comment: Maybe you need to install Eclipse for Java Developers or Eclipse for J2EE developers.

Comment: What happens if you go to Preferences->Java->Code Templates and click "restore defaults"?  Because I have code templates for comments that includes all the javadoc stuff.

Comment: it appears all the templates are present. I clicked "restore defaults" to be sure nothing crazy is going on. I just don't have that menu option.  My hunch is I have a subset of the "usual" features of eclipse.

Comment: Anyway, this is not what the OP is looking for. The question (which is a bit misleading) is not about generating the javadoc but adding javadoc "comments" in the code.

Answer (score 23):

At a place where you want javadoc, type in `/**`<NEWLINE> and it will create the template.

Comment: 1. that works, thank.  
2. that menu item isn't in any of the perspectives I use.

Comment: im interested to know what your perspective is

Comment: Generate Javadoc does not generate Javadoc comments.  It parses Javadoc comments and generates project documention (usually HTML)