# How to create Java method descriptions in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, methods, summary

I'm completely new to Java and the Eclipse IDE. I have background with .NET and Visual Studio. In VS when I want to create a description for a method, I just type three "/" characters and I get an auto-generated comment template, which looks similarly to the example below:

```
/// <summary>
/// This is my summary. Hope it is helpful. ;)
/// </summary>
/// <param name="item">Description of the item parameter.</param>
/// <returns></returns>
T Add(T item);
```

So, when somebody uses my method, the IDE will give him/her a hint, which is visualized right on top of the method's name. How can I achieve this in Eclipse, giving descriptions for my Java methods?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I generate Javadoc comments in Eclipse?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1777175/how-can-i-generate-javadoc-comments-in-eclipse)

Comment: On the line before your method, type /** then enter.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should use /** */ notation:

```
/** Comment */
private void method() {
}
```

It's called javadoc: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Javadoc

Answer (score 7):

```
/**
* regular
* @author John Doe
* @param 
* @return 
* @since 01-01-2000
* @version 1.0
* @exception PersonNotFoundException  gevonden
*/
```

Answer (score 5):

**Java:** Just put  `/**` before your method annotation and will generate auto. ;)

```
/**
 * This is my summary. Hope it is helpful. ;)
*/
T Add(T item);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can select a method, class, variable name and enter ALT+SHIFT+J in eclipse IDE to genereate auto java descriptions as below:-

```
/* (non-Javadoc)
 * @see javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet#doGet(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest, javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse)
 */
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    response.getWriter().append("Served at: ").append(request.getContextPath());
}
```